# How to authenticate API requests in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, request

I am currently building some sort of posts based web application using Laravel 5(.4). I have decided to load asynchronously the comment section for each post(and refresh it periodically). After some research I have decided to write a small integrated **REST API** (using the api routes of **Laravel**) that should answer to the requests made through **AJAX**.

However, I am facing the problem if **authenticating the incoming requests**. Take for example a request to post some comment. How exactly would you recommend to do that?

Comment: you could use a jwt or a simple token based auth.
Laravel 5.4 should have a token guard by default

Comment: BTW this is an opinionated question. So you could get some downvotes.

Comment: @GordonFreeman well, I was asking because I had no idea of the answer, so I also had no idea that the question is opinionated. Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Answer (score 1):

If you are making AJAX requests from browser and you are signed in then you don't need to use Laravel Passport tokens. 
You can define certain routes which will be using `web`,`auth` middleware on requests like `webapi/comments/get` like this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth]], function () {
        Route::get('webapi/comments/get', 'CommentsController@get');
}
```

And use `Auth` Facade as you do in web request i.e `Auth::check(), Auth::user()` etc. and return the data in JSON like this.

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function get(Request $request)
    {
         if($request->acceptsJson()){
            $data = array();

            // add data

            return response()->json([
                   "data"=> $data,
                   "status" => true
                  ]);
         }else{
            return abort(404);
         }

    }
}
```

You can also send `Accept` header in AJAX request as `application/json` and in controller check if request  `$request->acceptsJson()` and make your decision to show content when url is loaded from browser address bar or requested as AJAX.

Laravel Passport token are useful where there is no session and cookies are managed.

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

"Passport includes an authentication guard that will validate access tokens on incoming requests. Once you have configured the api guard to use the passport driver, you only need to specify the  auth:api middleware on any routes that require a valid access token" - from the Laraven Documentation. 

Apparently I have to configure passport, and after that configure the auth:api middleware to use the passport driver. Correct me if I'm wrong, please :)